# kubectl: How to get more detailed logs?

Tags: kubernetes

How to get more details about what is actually the problem?

```
kubtectl logs foo-app-5695559f9c-ntrqf

Error from server (BadRequest): container "foo" in pod "foo-app-5695559f9c-ntrqf" 
      is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

I would like to see the http traffic between K8s and the container registry.

Answer (score 2):

If a container has not started, then there are no container logs from that pod to view, as appears to be the case.

To get more information about the pod or why the container may not be starting, you can use [`kubectl describe pod`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#describe) which should show you both the pod status and the events relevant to the given pod:

```
kubectl describe pod <pod-name> --namespace <namespace>
```

The most common error is an access issue to the registry. Make sure you have an `imagePullSecrets` set for the registry that you're trying to pull from.

See: [How to pull image from a private registry.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

Answer (score 1):

If your image pull secret is correct and you are able to reach container registry from your kubernetes cluster, what i would do in this case is use contianer runtime(docker,containerd) that my kubernetes cluster is using to pull the image and see what is causing the issue, which gives more detail logs and can be run in debug mode.

For Docker Set `"debug": true` in the `daemon.json` configuration.

For Containerd set:

```
[debug]
        level = "debug"
```

in /etc/containerd/config.toml.